# SQL Library exercises (Microsoft Access)

Tags: ms-access, count, sql-date-functions

I almost finished all exercises, but somehow I can't solve this one.

The question is:

> Make a list of books by title and author, where each book indicates how often it is borrowed after September 1, 2014

I'm using Microsoft ACCESS and this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    Title, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME,
    COUNT(BORROWINGS.booknumber)
FROM 
    Books, Authors, Borrowings
WHERE 
    BOOKS.Booknumber = BORROWINGS.Booknumber 
    AND BOOKS.Authornumber = Authors.Authornumber 
    AND DateBorrowed > #1-9-2014#` (D/M/Y)  
GROUP BY 
    TITLE, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME;
```

I got some results, but they are wrong because I checked if my results matched the table *Borrowings* and it didn't. My results says the books are borrowed many more times after September 1, 2014 than the table *Borrowings* shows. How come?

Answer (score 0):

try to JOIN your tables.
In your Query design form insert your three table: Books, Authors and Borrowings.

Create a Join From Books.BookNumber to Borrowings.BookNumber selecting all records of Books and matching records from Borrowings, and Book.Author (or so ever) to AuthorID in the Author Table.

So you will Output the field Books.BookNumber, Authors.FirstName and Authors.Lastname and Borrowings.DateBorrowed.

In the Total row select Count as aggregation formula for the field DateBorrowed.

Set your WHERE condition only to DateBorrowed ( > #1-9-2014#)

In the SQL view you will find your SQL code out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I didn't know how JOIN worked before but I will use it in my other assignments now.